# Bugzilla REST API bug creation return 401 error

Tags: rest, bugzilla

I upgraded bugzilla from 3.4.6 to 5.0.3. The bugzilla 5.0.3 is working fine after upgrade. I am trying to a java application to create bugs in bugzilla using bugzilla's REST APIs. I can sucessfully search a bug from the java using Sping's RestTemplate using the api_key to authenticate. But the bug creation is not working I am getting 401 (Authorization error) even though I am passing the correct Authorization in the header of the request. Java code is below. I have also added the errorlog from bugzilla and the .htaccess file. I have tried almost possible combination of authorization in the header - like passing Bugzilla_api_key or api_key or Bugzilla_api_token or all of them, nothing works always get 401. The credentials are valid because I can successfully create a bug using Advanced Rest Client.

```
public void createBug(JSONObject json) {
            String url = bugzillaRestUrl + "bug";
            Class<String> responseType = String.class;
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.add("Bugzilla_api_key",TOKEN);
            headers.add("Bugzilla_api_token",this.login());

            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + getBase64Credentials());
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(json.toString(), headers);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            try {
                ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, responseType);
                System.out.println(result.getBody());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    

            } finally {

            }

    }
    private String getBase64Credentials(){
        String plainCreds = "<user>" + ":" + "<password>";
        byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
        return new String(base64CredsBytes);
    }
```

### errorlog below

```
[19239] 01/24/18 12:22:20 global/user-error.html.tmpl login_required 192.168.1.48
[19239] $param(POSTDATA) = "{\"summary\":\"New Test bug - please disregard 2\",\"product\":\"ASIPay\",\"component\":\"Account Search\",\"alias\":\"SomAlias2\",\"priority\":\"P1\",\"version\":\"unspecified\",\"op_sys\":\"All\",\"rep_platform\":\"All\"}";
[19239] $env(BZ_CACHE_CONTROL) = 1;
[19239] $env(CONTENT_LENGTH) = 191;
[19239] $env(CONTENT_TYPE) = "application/json";
[19239] $env(DOCUMENT_ROOT) = "/var/www/bugzilla";
[19239] $env(GATEWAY_INTERFACE) = "CGI/1.1";
[19239] $env(HTTP_ACCEPT) = "application/json";
[19239] $env(HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET) = "big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1166, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp";
[19239] $env(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION) = "Basic dWNob3dkaHVyeUBpbm5vdmVzdHN5c3RlbXMuY29tOlRlc3R4ITIz";
[19239] $env(HTTP_BUGZILLA_API_KEY) = "srZeBYyELYP4ddVwpnmvhgLS2NzdjD4d5elYzB8h";
[19239] $env(HTTP_BUGZILLA_API_TOKEN) = "60-yxl1VnhvBz";
[19239] $env(HTTP_CONNECTION) = "keep-alive";
[19239] $env(HTTP_HOST) = "192.168.1.103";
[19239] $env(HTTP_USER_AGENT) = "Java/1.8.0_60";
[19239] $env(PATH) = "";
[19239] $env(PATH_INFO) = "/bug";
[19239] $env(PATH_TRANSLATED) = "/var/www/bugzilla/bug";
[19239] $env(QUERY_STRING) = "";
[19239] $env(REDIRECT_BZ_CACHE_CONTROL) = 1;
[19239] $env(REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION) = "Basic dWNob3dkaHVyeUBpbm5vdmVzdHN5c3RlbXMuY29tOlRlc3R4ITIz";
[19239] $env(REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI) = "http://192.168.1.103/bugzilla/rest/bug";
[19239] $env(REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL) = "/bugzilla/rest/bug";
[19239] $env(REDIRECT_STATUS) = 200;
[19239] $env(REDIRECT_URL) = "/bugzilla/rest/bug";
[19239] $env(REMOTE_ADDR) = "192.168.1.48";
[19239] $env(REMOTE_PORT) = 50834;
[19239] $env(REQUEST_METHOD) = "POST";
[19239] $env(REQUEST_URI) = "/bugzilla/rest/bug";
[19239] $env(SCRIPT_FILENAME) = "/var/www/bugzilla/rest.cgi";
[19239] $env(SCRIPT_NAME) = "/rest.cgi";
[19239] $env(SCRIPT_URI) = "http://192.168.1.103/bugzilla/rest/bug";
[19239] $env(SCRIPT_URL) = "/bugzilla/rest/bug";
[19239] $env(SERVER_ADDR) = "192.168.1.103";
[19239] $env(SERVER_ADMIN) = "root\@localhost";
[19239] $env(SERVER_NAME) = "192.168.1.103";
[19239] $env(SERVER_PORT) = 80;
[19239] $env(SERVER_PROTOCOL) = "HTTP/1.1";
[19239] $env(SERVER_SIGNATURE) = "<address>Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at 192.168.1.103 Port 80</address>\n";
[19239] $env(SERVER_SOFTWARE) = "Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)";
[19239] $env(TEST2_ACTIVE) = 1;
[19239] $env(TEST_ACTIVE) = 1;
```

---

.htaccess file

```
# Don't allow people to retrieve non-cgi executable files or our private data
<FilesMatch (\.pm|\.pl|\.tmpl|localconfig.*)$>
  <IfModule mod_version.c>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_version.c>
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
  <FilesMatch (\.js|\.css)$>
    ExpiresActive On
    # According to RFC 2616, "1 year in the future" means "never expire".
    # We change the name of the file's URL whenever its modification date
    # changes, so browsers can cache any individual JS or CSS URL forever.
    # However, since all JS and CSS URLs involve a ? in them (for the changing
    # name) we have to explicitly set an Expires header or browsers won't
    # *ever* cache them.
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 years"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </FilesMatch>

  # This lets Bugzilla know that we are properly sending Cache-Control
  # and Expires headers for CSS and JS files.
  SetEnv BZ_CACHE_CONTROL 1
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteOptions inherit
  RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ rest.cgi/$1 [NE]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

---

bugzilla.vhost file

```
Alias /bugzilla /var/www/bugzilla
<Directory /var/www/bugzilla>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    AllowOverride All
#    Order allow,deny
#    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bugzilla
    ServerName 192.168.1.103:80
    ErrorLog logs/bugzilla-error_log
    CustomLog logs/bugzilla-access_log common
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Even for POST requests (like creating a bug in Bugzilla) we need to pass the api_key as query parameter like we do for GET requests.

```
public void createBug(JSONObject json) {
            String url = bugzillaRestUrl + "bug?api_key=" + API_KEY;
            Class<String> responseType = String.class;
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(json.toString(), headers);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            try {
                ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, responseType);
                System.out.println(result.getBody());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    

            } finally {

            }

    }
```

where the API_KEY can be generated from the Preferences->API Keys page in Bugzilla